# Table driven tests in Python using pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'd like to have a standard test template to copy from when solving coding puzzles. Typically, I would need to write multiple test functions to check if my function is working as expected. However, it's easier to write table-driven tests. In this case, all I would need to do to add a new test case is define the name, inputs and expected values for the new test case. I was inspired by https://lorenzopeppoloni.com/tabledriventestspy/.

I'd appreciate any advice on optimizing this template further - either make it more concise or improve the readability of the code or the test output.

I explain the various choices I made below:

- Using `pytest` rather than `unittest`

  Unittest doesn't allow you to parametrize tests. We could loop over multiple `TestData` points within a single test case, however, Unitest would treat it as a single test case. For example, if the first `TestData` point fails, it wouldn't bother testing the rest. Pytest provides [parametrize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html#parametrize-basics) which solves this problem.
- Using dataclass

  This makes the `testdata` definition a bit more readable as the `id`, `input` and `expected` values are clearly labelled.
- `__test__ = False` on `TestData` class

  I added this to avoid Pytest throwing a warning. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58624641/how-to-prevent-pytestcollectionwarning-when-testing-class-testament-via-pytest
- Defining tests under a `TestClass`

  I could have defined the test without putting it within a class. However, classes are useful to group test cases. There may be instances where I want to create separate classes to group similar tests.
- `input` is a tuple

  In this case, the input could have just been a string. However, in general, my function would take multiple parameters. So, in the general case, my input will be a tuple that I later unpack.

```
import pytest
from dataclasses import dataclass

def say_hello(name: str) -> str:
    return f"Hello {name}"

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TESTS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@dataclass
class TestData:
    id: str
    input: tuple
    expected: any
    __test__ = False


class TestClass:
    testdata = [
        TestData(id="boy name", input=("Vipin",), expected="Hello Vipin"),
        TestData(id="girl name", input=("Geethu",), expected="FAIL"),
    ]

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "input,expected",
        map(lambda x: (x.input, x.expected), testdata),
        ids=map(lambda x: x.id, testdata),
    )
    def test(self, input, expected):
        actual = say_hello(*input)
        assert actual == expected


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main()
```

The above test includes a failing test case on purpose. This is so that I can check that the test output reads well. Here is the test output. Note how the name of test, the inputs and the expected value are all made obvious.

```
============================================================================================ FAILURES ============================================================================================
___________________________________________________________________________________ TestClass.test[girl name] ____________________________________________________________________________________

self = <hello_world_test.TestClass object at 0x10181ad00>, input = ('Geethu',), expected = 'FAIL'

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "input,expected",
        map(lambda x: (x.input, x.expected), testdata),
        ids=map(lambda x: x.id, testdata),
    )
    def test(self, input, expected):
        actual = say_hello(*input)
>       assert actual == expected
E       AssertionError: assert 'Hello Geethu' == 'FAIL'
E         - FAIL
E         + Hello Geethu

hello_world_test.py:32: AssertionError
==================================================================================== short test summary info =====================================================================================
FAILED hello_world_test.py::TestClass::test[girl name] - AssertionError: assert 'Hello Geethu' == 'FAIL'
================================================================================= 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.49s ==================================================================================
```